# Retrieve photos via USB from Canon EOS 350D

Tags: fedora, usb, camera, file-transfer

I have a Canon EOS 350D which has a [bent pin in the CF slot](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/83314/4661). Therefore I do not want to take out the card more often then needed now, retrieving the images via the mini-USB port should be possible, in principle.

There are two options I can set the camera to:

- Print/PTP
- PC Connection

See this screenshot of the camera menu:

[image]

Neither option lets anything appear in Dolphin (file manager) or `/dev`. How can I retrieve the images from my camera?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use Digikam. With Digikam you can import from a variety of cameras, the 350D should be supported.

Comment: Interesting, I have tried that with Digikam a couple weeks ago on both camera settings and could not get any pictures. Today it just worked.

Comment: Great! I think this is the best advice together with darktable.

Answer (score 2):

General answer.

"PC connection" could be equal to either "Mass storage" which should make the camera crate an emulated harddisk, or set the camera to "MTP mode"

For MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) you may need to install e.g. `mtp-tools`
*(as in `sudo apt-get install jmtpfs mtp-tools` for Ubuntu)*